# Running untrusted code in Lua via loadstring

Tags: lua

I'm working with a modding api for a game, for those curious it's factorio but it's not really relevant, and the Lua environment is HEAVILY limited, blocking functions like `setfenv`, it's a 5.1 environment and I do have access to loadstring, pcall, etc. My question is how would you recommend running 'unsafe' code that is provided by a user and limiting what functions they can access without access to environment modification functions? (Preferably whitelist functions/values instead of blacklist, but I'll take whatever I can get)

Comment: If you're willing to heavily sacrifice performance, there are several Lua-in-Lua emulators available. (http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaInterpreterInLua)

Answer (score 4):

In Lua 5.1 you need setfenv to create a secure sandbox (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34388499/5287638) for a typical procedure). So if you don't have access to setfenv, then I don't think it can't be done.

Then again, if the environment you're working in has disabled setfenv and has put a wrapper around loadstring to avoid malicious bytecode loading (again, see the answer I linked) then you might be able to run the script without setting up a special environment for it. It really depends on the details of your current environment as to whether it's safe or not.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for a late answer (you've probably moved on by now) but it is possible to do this using the built in load function. You can supply a fourth argument to the function which is a custom environment and it returns a function. You can pass a function, a string, or possibly even a thread (I think) to load and get the result you want. I was also having this problem and I thought I'd answer it for future users.

Here is a link to the documentation on the lua site for load: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load
I have tested this to ensure it works properly in Factorio and it appears to work as intended.

Comment: That's 5.2, not 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in Lua 5.1 without `setfenv` or `debug.setfenv`. In newer versions, the `load` function allows specifying the environment of the new function (which is just an upvalue in those Lua versions), but note that it is not enough to protect the host environment! You should also set the `mode` parameter to `"t"`, since there is no protection against malicious binary chunks.

Even when you think the guest code cannot run any global function once you give it your own environment, beware that there is one exception ‒ the `string` table, accessible through every string since it is set as the `__index` metamethod of the string type. Most functions there are harmless, but `string.dump` can be used to serialize a Lua function, which can lead to private data leaking:

```lua
local function secret_func()
  auth("very_secret_key")
end

local custom_env = {
  print = print,
  secret_func = secret_func
}

local code = [[
print(("").dump(secret_func))
]]

load(code, nil, "t", custom_env)()
```

Observe `very_secret_key` being in the printed code. You can "fix" this simply by setting `string.dump = nil`, or, if there is other code that needs to rely on it, just make it inaccessible through `__index`:

```lua
local string_index = {}
for k, v in pairs(string) do
  string_index[k] = v
end
string_index.dump = nil
debug.getmetatable("").__index = string_index
```